# Is it grammatical to put 2 question marks in one sentence?

Tags: grammar

The only difference between these 2 sentences is the punctuation

> Adverbs often answer the questions "how" and "in what way".
>
> Adverbs often answer the questions "how?" and "in what way?"

I guess the first one is grammatical. The question is the 2nd. Is it grammatical to put 2 or more question marks in one sentence?

Comment: They are in quoted speech, so not really part of the enclosing sentence. Consider: My brother asked "When did you arrive?" and immediately "When are you leaving?"

Comment: Insofar as your sentences are statements rather than questions, I don't see the need for any question marks at all. Compare: **The question of how to approach them came up in the discussion.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [The Punctuation Guide](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/terminal-points.html) you don't need a question mark within the parentheses in this case supposing they function in a similar way.

Based on my overall knowledge of English the question mark here is nothing but an unnecessary addition probably since it does not follow any common writing styles I know of.

However, there is a slight chance that in this case you are not just addressing the questions as statements but actually referring to them as to a questions, which means we can put emphasis and place question marks there, but by doing so I would suggest you capitalize the first letters.

- Adverbs often answer the questions "How?" and "In what way?".

Having said that I would still stick to the more common way without the question marks included.

Comment: Does "parentheses" actually refer to a pair of quotation marks?

Comment: @WXJ96163 They work alike in most cases. Unfortunately I couldn't find information concerning quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is the first one in my OP you preferred? Do I need to add extra modification to that?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Use the former style.